# Rails migrations best practise- many similar migrations or one big?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

I have to add one column to almost 10 tables. What do you think is the best way to do that?

- Make a one migration with weird name and use a loop to change column in each model
- Make 10 migrations with similar content but having nice names like: add_extra_field_to_user

Comment: Is all that new columns related to one feature?

Comment: @denis Kind of. The goal is to add extra field for street name to each model that has an address data.

Comment: If any of them are the same address, you do not want to be duplicating it in different tables, but just referring to one table that contains the information.

Comment: Right. Most probably it will be polymorphic associations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for 10. Additional advantage is that you can run them, and rollback them seperately. Also I would always give readability priority, especially when otherwisee you get weird names ;)